# How can I visualize a model created for my by AutoML Table in Google Cloud?

Tags: google-cloud-automl

I have seen in Google I/O  presentations nice images showing what the AutoML (Table) created model actually looks like. (Such models have many layers, some "skipping" connections between layers, and so forth. Visualizing them helps understand better what the model is trying to do.)

Is there a  place that shows documentation or example on how to do this visualization?

AutoML is great, I would like to understand my models better.

Comment: I have received the following helpful reply on a google group. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cloud-automl-tables-discuss/EFt-fRqK0m0

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is a direct way to do visualization on auto ml models. Although you can download an edge model and then load it in tensorflow, then use
`model.summary()`